# Incoming and outcoming calls info in android

Tags: android, call, state

Maybe my question dublicate, but read many questions on STACK, articles and blog on other sites and didnt find answer how to take  outcoming calls time info...(( Wrote many receivers, phone state and call listeners, tested constants (CALL_STATE_IDLE, CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK,CALL_STATE_RINGING) but they have not yielded any results... will be glad to receive any suggestions or ideas. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access CallLog content provider (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) along with a ContentObserver (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) to do this. ContentObserver can be notified for any changes in CallLog content provider and you can check for the latest record from CallLog's Calls table and find all the information there.